# How to make max-height work properly in IE6,IE7?

Tags: css

```
max-height:600px;
```

The above works as `height:600px` in IE7,and not working at all in IE6.

Comment: Did my answer work for you? If sp, I'd appreciate it if you accepted it as an answer :) thanks!

Answer (score 2):

IE6 doesn't support this. Use conditional comments to feed an it an IE6-only stylesheet, and use IE's proprietary "expression" attribute to use some javascript.

```
#id {
   height: expression( this.scrollHeight > 332 ? "333px" : "auto" );
}
```

See http://perishablepress.com/press/2007/01/16/maximum-and-minimum-height-and-width-in-internet-explorer/

Answer (score 1):

For IE7, max-height works as intended if you specify a strict doctype in your html:

Remember though, certain elements/attributes allowed in a transitional doctype are not supported in strict.  Here's a good article that lists them:
http://24ways.org/2005/transitional-vs-strict-markup